# Wrap widget is not working with Listview.builder

Tags: flutter

```dart
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    // physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
    // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: medDays.length,
    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
      return Wrap(
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          Radio(
              value: index,
              groupValue: radioCondition,
              activeColor: cardColor,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  radioCondition = val;
                  pageCondition = true;
                });
              }),
          Text(
            medDays[index].toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
    })),
```

Wrap widget is not working with listview.builder. The Wrap widget is suppose to show the widget in proper way, like row form when the space became less it moves to next line but it showing me in column form.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Wrap` instead of a `ListView`. Not a `Wrap` ìnside a `ListView`. Every single item has their own `Wrap` now, but you want every item in a single `Wrap`

Try this

```
Wrap(
  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  children: [
    for (final (index, day) in medDays.indexed)
      Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Radio(
              value: index,
              groupValue: radioCondition,
              activeColor: cardColor,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  radioCondition = val;
                  pageCondition = true;
                });
              }),
          Text(
            day.toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
  ],
),
```